# sequence of non-negative functions $f_n$ tending to $0$ pointwise with $\int f_n \to 0$, but no integrable $g$ such that $f_n \leq g$ for all $n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a sequence of non-negative functions $f_n$ tending to $0$ pointwise such that $\int f_n \to 0$, but there is no integrable function $g$ such that $f_n \leq g$ for all $n$.

Define the piecewise function $f_n: \mathbb{R}\backslash 0 \to \mathbb{R}^+$ as,
\begin{equation}
f_n = \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{ if } x \in (-\infty,  -\frac1n]\\
        n^2 x + n & \text{ if } x \in (1, 0]\\
        -n^2 x + n & \text{ if } x \in (0, \frac1n]\\
       0 & \text{ if } x \in (\frac1n, \infty)
    \end{cases}\end{equation}

Clearly as $n \to \infty$ it's clear that each point in $\mathbb{R}\backslash 0$ converges to $0$. Furthermore, $\int f_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$. Now I would like to show that any $g\geq f_n$ must not be integrable, that is $\int g = \infty$. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure your functions are right? Seems to me $f_n$ can easily be bounded above by $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}$, and is supported within $[-1,1]$, so $g=2\cdot \chi_{[-1,1]}$ is a dominating function.

Comment: Here $f_n\leq \chi_{[-1,1]}$.

Comment: I changed it to something more sensible. i'm sorry about that

Comment: your second case is still meaningless. I strongly suggest you forget explicit formulae, and draw pictures here (especially since these are simple piecewise-linear functions, so it takes more effort to give the formulas than sketching them).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a sequence of functions with no dominating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854712/finding-a-sequence-of-functions-with-no-dominating-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of coming up with an example is to let $f_n$ be a triangle function supported on $[n,n+1]$ with height $\frac{2}{n}$, so that $\int f_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then, $f_n\to 0$ pointwise and $\int f_n\to 0$. Then, every (necessarily non-negative) measurable function $g$ such that $g\geq f_n$ for all $n$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb{R}}g\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\infty.
\end{align}